# IE11 compatibility questions

Tags: windows, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, windows-8.1

We have a pretty huge HTML / JavaScript application written in a 15 year span that several programmers updated, edited and patched. We use this application on our computers (about 60 PCs) to teach languages online. The PCs that are used by our teachers are all Windows 8.1 (last update made in 2015), and the current IE version that's running the application is (it works only on IE):

Version: 11.0.9600.17937
Update version: 11.0.22

The decision to stop updating the computers was made due to the worry of compatibility issues. I'm taking over the position of the previous IT guy and I think it would be mandatory to update all machines with Windows 10 and the latest version of IE.

I would like to know your opinion and if there could be any compatibility issues between the IE11 version we are currently using and the latest version available on Windows 10.

I'm going to test myself the whole thing anyway.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very hard to say. Some the compatibility issues you might see, might actually be a result of different system or user account policies in different versions or editions of Windows; others might genuinely be the disparities between different versions of IE you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. All the 60 computers have exactly the same specs, OS and settings. They are all stand alone pc and are not part of a domain.